# How to use jQuery when redrawing a chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I currently have a chart which I place in my page by calling

```
function myChart(aParameter) {
  // here is some code which queries data based on aParameter
  // and sets a variable later used for series: [...] in the chart below

  $("#mychartid").highcharts({...})
}
```

This function is then called when a choice on some radio buttons is done:

```
$('#productselect input[type=radio]').change(function(){
    myChart($(this).val())
      })
```

It works fine, but is not effective: the complete redrawing of the chart moves the page and I need to scroll back on the chart.

When searching for a solution, I found [a good question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14100011/highcharts-redraw-vs-new-highcharts-chart) which gives some details on how to correctly update a chart (which I hope will fix my issue). It suggests to first create a chart (`chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartOptions)`) and then use incantations of `chart.series[0].setData(data,true);` to update the data.

The point I am missing is **how to initially position such a chart on my page (using jQuery)**, similar to my `$("#mychartid").highcharts({...})` above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still create the chart exactly as you are, except that you assign it to a variable. So

```
$("#mychartid").highcharts(chartOptions);
var chart = $("#mychartid").highcharts();
```

Then you can perform whatever actions you want on `chart`, including the

```
chart.series[0].setData(data,true);
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/3d3fuhbb/111/

** *UPDATED to correct code* **

Comment: Thanks. You mention that both do the same thing, but the update (via `chart.series[0].setData(data,true);`) will be in-place, right? In other words the browser will notice a change in the DOM but the chart does not need to be rewritten and its size set to zero, then recalculated (this is, I suppose, what is causing the page drift)?

Comment: I just modified my code to have `chart = $("#mychartid").highcharts({...})`. It breaks when I want to do a `chart.series[0].setData(data,true);`. When checking `chart`in DevTools, it is a `div`, not a highcharts object (see http://i.imgur.com/Pber22t.png for a screenshot)

Comment: Right. Sorry. Corrected code added to answer, with example

Comment: Thank you - this is exactly what I was looking for. And indeed - changing the values via `setData` solves the problem of the page scrolling (the change is in situ)