# window.resize() in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

```js
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});

//High Chart JS
$(function () {
  $('#container').highcharts({

    backgroundColor: {
      stops: [
        [0, '#2a2a2b'],
        [1, '#3e3e40']
      ]
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'area',
      backgroundColor: "#000"
    },
    title: {
      text: 'US and USSR nuclear stockpiles',
      color: '#fff'
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Source: <a>' +
      'Xylines</a>'
    },
    xAxis: {
      allowDecimals: false,
      labels: {
        formatter: function () {
          return this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year
        }
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Nuclear weapon states'
      },
      labels: {
        formatter: function () {
          return this.value / 1000 + 'k';
        }
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: '{series.name} produced <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>warheads in {point.x}'
    },
    plotOptions: {
      area: {
        pointStart: 1940,
        marker: {
          enabled: false,
          symbol: 'circle',
          radius: 2,
          states: {
            hover: {
              enabled: true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'USA',
      data: [null, null, null, null, null, 6, 11, 32, 110, 235, 369, 640,
             1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618, 6444, 9822, 15468, 20434, 24126,
             27387, 29459, 31056, 31982, 32040, 31233, 29224, 27342, 26662,
             26956, 27912, 28999, 28965, 27826, 25579, 25722, 24826, 24605,
             24304, 23464, 23708, 24099, 24357, 24237, 24401, 24344, 23586,
             22380, 21004, 17287, 14747, 13076, 12555, 12144, 11009, 10950,
             10871, 10824, 10577, 10527, 10475, 10421, 10358, 10295, 10104]
    }, {
      name: 'USSR/Russia',
      data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
             5, 25, 50, 120, 150, 200, 426, 660, 869, 1060, 1605, 2471, 3322,
             4238, 5221, 6129, 7089, 8339, 9399, 10538, 11643, 13092, 14478,
             15915, 17385, 19055, 21205, 23044, 25393, 27935, 30062, 32049,
             33952, 35804, 37431, 39197, 45000, 43000, 41000, 39000, 37000,
             35000, 33000, 31000, 29000, 27000, 25000, 24000, 23000, 22000,
             21000, 20000, 19000, 18000, 18000, 17000, 16000]
    }]
  });
});
```

```css
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Simple Sidebar (http://startbootstrap.com/)
 * Copyright 2013-2016 Start Bootstrap
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap/blob/gh-pages/LICENSE)
 */

/* Toggle Styles */

#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 220px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 220px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -220px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 220px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -220px;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 220px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 220px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 52px;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 220px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 52px;
    }

    #page-content-wrapper {
        padding: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
        padding-left: 52px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/js/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Sidebar -->
<div id="wrapper">

  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
      <li class="sidebar-brand">
        <a href="#">
         Logo
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Overview</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Events</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

  <!-- Page Content -->
  <div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background:#000">
      <div id="container" style="background:#000"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

</div>
```

When I toggle the menu in Large and Medium screen I want the Chart to redrawn or resized, I tried many but dint got any output.

I tried this
`$(window).resize();`
`#container: redraw();`

here's the jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/dLujgtf9/

Can someone help me please, I got irritated up in this from last 2 days, my Boss is shouting like hell.....

Thanks & regards

## zeasts

Comment: As I can see on the fiddle, the container it's wrapped in is resizing so please try invoking the `reflow()` method on highcharts before considering others: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.reflow

Comment: have you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14100011/highcharts-redraw-vs-new-highcharts-chart

Comment: `redraw()` and `reflow()` are for different purposes. `redraw()` is to only be used if data is added dynamically. From what I can see, (and what I have tried) it does NOT alter the size of it. `reflow()` does. Please see the API link for reference

Comment: `reflow()` is not working, @wmash

Comment: I checked that link, but couldn't understand what to do where :( as I'm very new to jQuery & JS @vijayP

Comment: I have edited your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dLujgtf9/8/. I attempted to apply a `setInterval` method. This partially works as the chart reflows perfectly when the alert is dismissed but not if the alert is not there. It's almost like it needs something before it to execute properly. Anyway, I'll have another look when I can but this is at least a step in the right direction :)

Comment: yup that is what I really expecting but the alert is messing up...

Comment: Have posted an answer with updated jsFiddle

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have managed to amend the fiddle again to suit your needs I think: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dLujgtf9/12/)

Adding an anonymous function into the mix seemed to sort it:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $("#container").highcharts().reflow();
}, 1);
```

Comment: Worked properly Thanks @wmash

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why I have to requery, but this works for me.

```
    angular.element(window).trigger('resize');
    var allCharts = document.querySelectorAll('[data-highcharts-chart]');
    for(var x = 0; x<allCharts.length; x++){
        angular.element('[data-highcharts-chart=' + x + ']').highcharts().reflow();
    }
```

Comment: am not using in angularjs :( @httpette

Comment: so modify however you wish with jquery

Answer (score -3):

I added the following code and it works fine. It doesn't redraw but it resized.

```
$(window).resize(function() {

             $("#container").width($(window).width()-250);

     });
```

PS: I modified the following css setting:

@media(min-width:200px)

Are you sure you can't resize?

Comment: In my end its not at working, yup I cannot resize. @yu wayne

Comment: This is resizing the container which OP has already accomplished. it's resizing the chart they are struggling with

Comment: If you resize the container, it should also resize the chart. Please see the post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768565/resize-height-with-highcharts. And my code did work on my computer(both container and chart). Maybe your can try to remove some of the css reference.

Comment: @yuwayne that's if the window is resized. Highcharts have only set up defaults for when the window is resized not just it's wrapping container. So, if the container is resized but the window is not, that event will not fire