# Why highchart returning " Typeerror : undefined variable byte "?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to draw a graph with the help of high chart and also using load event I am trying to add values after each 1 second to the graph.

In this graph I also want to show axis as Mb,Kb,,Gb data. So I am writing a function to return the byte values as Mb,Kb,Gb (for both series and tooltip)

This is my code :

```
// highchart options :
var series1, series2 ;

var chart = {
          type: 'bar',
              events: {
                    load: function () {
                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        series1 = this.series[0];
                        series2 = this.series[1];

                        setInterval(function () {

                            add_function();

                        }, 1000);//call function each 1 second
                    }
                }


};

var tooltip = { 
          enabled: true, 
          formatter: function() { return fbytes(this.y,2);} 
}; 

var plotOptions = { 
          bar: { 
          }, 
          series: { 
            dataLabels: { 
                enabled: true, 
                formatter: function() { return fbytes(this.y,2);}, 
                inside: true, 
                style: {fontWeight: 'number'} 
            },   
            pointPadding: 0, 
            pointWidth:38 
          }, 
          column : { 
             grouping: true 
          }     
};

series= [
            {
             name: 'old',
             color: '#f9a80e',
             data: [,]
            }, 
            {
                name: 'new',
                color: '#89897f',
                data: [,]
            }
];
```

and the load event function is :

```
Array.max = function (array) { 
        return Math.max.apply(Math, array); 
}; 
Array.min = function (array) { 
        return Math.min.apply(Math, array); 
}; 

add_function()
{ 
    var arr[];
    //getting array values here 
    var min_value = Array.min(arr); 
    var max_value = Array.max(arr); 

    var chart2 = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart2.yAxis[0].update({max:max_value, min: 0}, true); 

    series1.setData([arr[0],arr[2]], true, true); 
    series2.setData([arr[1],arr[3]], true, true);
  }
```

and the conversion function :

```
function fbytes(bytes, precision) { 
    var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB']; 
    var posttxt = 0; 
    if (bytes == 0) return '0 Bytes'; 
    if (bytes < 1024) { 
            return Number(bytes) + " " + sizes[posttxt]; 
    } 
    while( bytes >= 1024 ) { 
            posttxt++; 
            bytes = bytes / 1024; 
    } 
    return Math.round(bytes.toPrecision(precision)) + " " + sizes[posttxt]; 
}
```

**my logic**  : i got some array values randomly and i am displaying this data on the graph .

**problem facing** : I didn't get `this.y` value inside `series` . When i print this value inside

```
 series: { 
            dataLabels: { 
                enabled: true, 
                formatter: function() { return fbytes(this.y,2);}, 
                inside: true, 
                style: {fontWeight: 'number'} 
            },
```

I am getting `this.y = undefined` . What is happening ?

Any mistake in the code ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: I think , you can draw the chart with first-coming values then update it with method chart.series[0].setData(data,true); and I believe you can find many resources regarding your issue on SO. and a useful link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14100011/highcharts-redraw-vs-new-highcharts-chart.

Comment: How can i draw at the first time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created demo using your code and modified add_function() a little bit. Did you mean something like this?

```
function add_function(series1, series2) {
    var chart2 = $('#container').highcharts(),
      increment = 1024,
      min_value,
      max_value,
      newVal1 = [],
      newVal2 = [];

    if (!series1.data.length && !series2.data.length) {
        var arr = [512, 128, 1024, 0];

        min_value = Array.min(arr);
        max_value = Array.max(arr);

        newVal1 = [arr[0], arr[2]];
        newVal2 = [arr[1], arr[3]];
    } else {
        series1.yData.forEach(function(sEl, sInx) {
            newVal1.push(sEl + increment);
        });

        series2.yData.forEach(function(sEl, sInx) {
            newVal2.push(sEl + increment);
        });
        max_value = Array.max(newVal1.concat(newVal2));
    }

    chart2.yAxis[0].update({
        max: max_value,
        min: 0
    }, true);

    series1.setData(newVal1, true, true);
    series2.setData(newVal2, true, true);
}
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/js3g311q/

Comment: But i got "undefined" again  . inside this.y of `formatter: function() { return fbytes(this.y,2);}, ` series data

Comment: What do you mean that you get ‘undefined’? As you can see in the example, data labels and tooltips content display as it should.